# HTML5 Shiv Google CDN Link Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, html5shiv

This Shiv Google CDN Link Not Working. What Should I Do?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: you should stop depending on external files. host it yourself. that way will work in intranet, too.

Comment: Place this code in head section of your html.

Comment: I Did But It's Not Working.

Comment: well, if below answer is useful please accept this as an answer...

Answer (score 23):

This was happening  because the CDN link has been updated for html5shiv.

Try [this from CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html5shiv) instead:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: should I even bother with an html5shiv?  is anyone really still using an ancient version of IE?

Answer (score 1):

It's good but I think is better don't add `https://`

So try with:

```
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js"
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2b802d651dbe4305221cc7c4a2e45123b9e8b699